# Firefox address bar not working after update to 50.0

Tags: firefox

A couple of days ago I updated my Firefox in Ubuntu 16.04 to 50.0. Now when I type and address in the address bar, it doesn't work on Intro nor click on the arrow next to it. I tried a solution I found online (https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1070999 ), but it doesn't work. Deleting the sqlite files didn't solve the issue.

Anyone else has this problem or know how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Firefox 50.1.0 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Fix: Disable InstantFox add-on.

I tried repairing and rebuilding the `places.sqlite` database in various ways as described [here on mozillazine](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Locked_or_damaged_places.sqlite) to no avail - I also had the same problem a couple of years ago on a different computer, and then rebuilding `places.sqlite` helped, but not this time.

Then I solved it by disabling the InstantFox add-on. I picked this because I knew it is designed to manipulate text in the address bar. When the add-on is disabled, the address bar works normally. When InstantFox is enabled, the problem returns.

I have sent an e-mail to InstantFox with this information.

If you don't have InstantFox, try disabling other add-ons one by one and re-check. Pick the ones that have something to do with the address bar first.

I don't know if the root cause is in Firefox itself, Ubuntu, or the add-on.

Answer (score 0):

the article from mozilla support you quoted suggests renaming your profile.

You can do that by

```
mv ~/.mozilla/firefox/????????.default/ ~/firefox-profile-backup
```

if firefox is running fine after that, try to re-install your themes, plugins and addons one by one to make sure none of that was causing the error.

After you did this, you can decide if anything from your old profile is worth the effort of extracting it from `~/firefox-profile-backup`

Answer (score 0):

One cause can be the add-on: New Tab from Location Bar (2.0.2016012102).

Try disabling or updating (in Tools | Add-ons) and restarting.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using InstantFox in your add-ons, this is probably the reason of your address bar issues.
I love InstantFox, because I can organize my Firefox shortcut keys very thoroughly and using InstantFox significantly saves me a lot of time navigating website searches.

There's workaround fix for the Firefox InstantFox issue, which makes InstantFox usable again and your address bar working. Check out this link [Firefox InstantFox Address Bar Issue Fix](http://www.pand.li/fix-instantfox)